# Arithmetic expression inside [[

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax, arithmetic-expressions

I have this code:

```
fruit=apple
flag=0

[[ $fruit = "apple" && ((flag == 0)) ]]  && echo "1"
[[ $fruit = "apple" && (($flag == 0)) ]] && echo "2"
[[ $fruit = "apple" && ((! flag)) ]]     && echo "3"
[[ $fruit = "apple" && ((! $flag)) ]]    && echo "4"
```

All of them are expected to echo something.  However, only the second statement works properly:

```
[[ $fruit = "apple" && (($flag == 0)) ]] && echo "2"
```

Why is this?  Won't arithmetic expressions work properly inside `[[ ]]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `==` works the same as `=` - it is a string comparision.

The `( )` inside `[[` `]]` is used to nest expressions. Ex. `[[ a = a && (b = b || c = d) ]]`

A non empty string is true. So `[[ some_string ]]` or `[[ "some other string" ]]` returns true. `[[ "" ]]` or `[[ '' ]]` returns false.

The `!` is negation.

> ```
> [[ $fruit = "apple" && ((flag == 0)) ]]
> ```

First the expansion of `$fruit` happens. So it becomes: `[[ "apple" = "apple" && ( ( "flag" == "0" ) ) ]]`. The `( )` are just braces, this is not arithemtic expansion. The string `"apple"` is equal to `"apple"`, but the string `"flag"` is not equal to string `"0"`, so it always returns with false.

> ```
> [[ $fruit = "apple" && (($flag == 0)) ]]
> ```

Because `$flag` is expanded, the `[[` sees: `[[ "apple" = "apple" && ((0 == 0)) ]]`. So the comparision happens to work, however `==` is doing string comparision.

> ```
>  [[ $fruit = "apple" && ((! flag)) ]]
> ```

The `flag` is a nonempty string, so it evaulates to true. The `! flag` evaulates to false.

> ```
>  [[ $fruit = "apple" && ((! $flag)) ]]
> ```

First `$flag` is expanded to `0`. As `0` is a nonempty string, it evaluates to true. The `! 0` evaluates to false. The `((! 0))` is false, so the whole expression returns nonzero.

> Won't arithmetic expressions work properly inside [[ ]]?

No, arithmetic expressions will not work inside `[[` `]]` the same way `[[ echo 1 ]]` does not work. The `echo 1 ]]` are arguments of `[[` builtin, not a standalone command. The same way `[[ (( 0 )) ]]` the `(( 0 )) ]]` are interpreted as arguments to `[[`.

Answer (score 2):

`((...))` is an arithmetic *command* (or statement); the arithmetic *expresson* is `$((...))`. You want

```
[[ $fruit = "apple" ]] && ((flag == 0)) && echo 1
# etc.
```

`[[ $fruit = apple && $((flag == 0)) ]]` would fail because `[[ ... ]]` would simply treat the evaluation of the arithmetic expression as a non-empty string (which is always true) rather than a boolean value.

For completeness, you could use a single `[[ ... ]]` command:

```
[[ $fruit = apple && flag -eq 0 ]] && echo 1
# etc
```